# Expressjs, async and middleware does not work properly

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, async.js

I'm doing tests with the framework expressjs in which I am creating a middleware that runs before the blocks of routes, but it does not work correctly.

I thought it could be my code that escapes the asynchronism and it does not run correctly, but I made a few changes to the code and the fault still escapes me. For more tests and attempts that I do, I can not find the bug.

My code is as follows:

```
function getData(hostname, number, string, cb) {

    async.waterfall([

        function(callback) {

            console.log('1');
            callback(null, null);
        },
        function(first, callback) {

            console.log('2');
            callback(null, null);
        },
        function(second, callback) {

            console.log('3');
            callback(null, []);
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {

        if( typeof cb === 'function') {

            return cb(null, results);
        }

        return results;
    });
}

// Request middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.locals['data'] = getData(req.hostname, 40, 'demo');

    next();
});

app.get('/demo', function(req, res) {

    res.send('Demo');

    console.log( JSON.stringify( res.locals ) );
});
```

Output on console is as follows (runs before that middleware returns the value):

> ```
> debug: 1
> {}
> GET /demo 200 10.654 ms - 9
> debug: 2
> debug: 3
> GET /favicon.ico - - ms - -
> ```

Only worked me correctly the code when it has been modified in the following way:

```
// Request middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if( req.method === 'GET' ) { // Only get request

        getData(req.hostname, 40, 'demo', function(err, data) {

            req.locals['data'] = data;

            next();
        });

    } else {

        next();
    }
});
```

But I think that it is to extend the code, duplicating calls and checks. I know because it does not work with the above code returning the value. I thought that with async waterfall running the code series and not returning it until the end, blocking the code.

Not should be synchronous and blocking the continuation of the code?

Thank you.

Comment: *"Not should be synchronous and blocking the continuation of the code?"* Yea, no. It wouldn't make sense to call it **async** if it were synchronous now would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the problem is that getData returns immediately. `async` does not 'escape async', it is a set of patterns around control flow *in an async fashion*. The result is still async. Also, DO NOT use the "deasync" library.

You might be interested in `koa` which uses generators (requires ES6 - i.e. Node v4 or Node 0.12 with --harmony) in order to let you write code that is less 'callback' driven. e.g. this would be koa middleware:

```
app.use(function*(next) {
  res.locals['data'] = yield getData(req.hostname, 40, 'demo');
  yield* next;
});
```

Comment: I do not know because it immediately returns the value, because debug messages are run sequentially. Previously I used Async and has never returned the value to indicate I in the main function. I am unaware if the call to getData is not blocking and why expressjs is still running the code. I saw the KOA framework but I saw him more complicated than espressjs (for a newbie like me).

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure what you're asking; you have the correct code in your question. There is no (sane) way to take something that is async in node and make it sync.  In express you have to use `next` to control program flow.

Comment: One alternative might be to look at promises - specifically `Bluebird` because you could write your function body as a series of promise statements and then at the end have `.nodeify(next)` but this is more avoiding understanding the problem than it is anything (and introducing understanding promises). It feels like you don't like having the if/else with two calls to `next` (promises would help with this)?

Answer (score -1):

You have a basic control flow problem here.  Your getData function is attempting to be both synchronous and asynchronous at the same time, while utilizing a purely asynchronous control flow.

The `async.waterfall` method is for executing a series of asynchronous methods, one after another, passing the results from one method to the next one in the chain.  If any of the methods calls back with an error, the waterfall will be interrupted.

Given this information, you should refactor your `getData()` method:

```
function getData(hostname, number, string, cb) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            console.log('1');
            callback();
        },
        function(first, callback) {
            console.log('2');
            callback();
        },
        function(second, callback) {
            console.log('3');
            callback(null, []);
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        return cb(err, results);
    });
}
```

Now, when wiring this method to your middleware, you can pass the `next` function as your callback value:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    getData(req.hostname, 40, 'demo', function(err, results) {
        res.locals.data = results;
        next(err);
    });
});
```

I hope this makes sense.  Basically you're just mixing and matching synchronous and asynchronous concepts here.

Comment: That is not the error, since at the end becomes a check if the value returned or executes the callback function. Thank you.

Comment: Again it seems like you're not understanding the difference between sync and async operations.  You have a waterfall which is meant for async flow, and then you try to invoke in synchronously.  Further, your protection in the async waterfall's final callback is actually wrong.  You return from the callback function, but not from the getData() function.  So your getData() will just return undefined if you don't give it a callback.

Comment: You're right, I do not understand very well the error. I am new to this. I have the code to work (similar to that you recommended me) but I don't understand why does the return, in other previous tests that I have made out of the espressjs middleware if worked me a similar code, so use it, to verify that it does not work.